# Error during the installation of oracle 11gxe

Tags: oracle, installation, oracle-xe

When I tried to install Oracle 11g XE into my machine (Windows XP media center edition, version 2002  SP3) I'm getting an error as

```
0x80040702 Description: Failed to load DLL:chkportDll2
```

I've googled, but not found any suitable answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think MCE are certified to run Oracle 11g XE.

Try

- [This thread](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=9918863#9918903) mentions deleting install paths found at

  ```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Folders
  ```

  key from the registry. You can try that. As always, ensure you have a **working** backup before you fiddle with the registry.
- Reinstalling SP3

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I canceled an Oracle installation and rebooted my pc.

Deleting keys as mentioned above did not help.

I solved the issue by downloading MySQL community installer. At the beginning of the installation it asked if I wanted to cancel the oracle installation that is currently in progress. I clicked yes, canceled the MySQL installation, restarted oracle installation which worked.

Comment: *"by downloading **MySQL** community installer"* ...? What has MySQL got to do with an Oracle installation problem?